# useState not re-rendring the componenet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm using useState hook but after changing the state, the component is not rending itself. I don't know what thing I'm missing.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import List from '@material-ui/core/List'
import ListTile from "./components/ListTile/ListTile"
import style from './App.module.css'
import InputField from "./components/inputField/InputField";

const App = () => {
    const [list, setList] = useState([])

    const onFormSubmitHandler = (data) => {
        list.push(data)
        setList(list)
    }

    return (
        <div className={style.outerDiv}>
            <h1 className={style.center}>CLister</h1>
            <InputField onSubmit={onFormSubmitHandler}/>
            <List component="nav">
                {list.map((data, index) =>
                     <ListTile index={index} body={data}/>
                )}
            </List>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your list an array a `reference` type in js. If you modify the list using push

like `list.push()` it will also modify the original list in your state ,as a result there will be no change in your state.

Example

```js
let list = [1, 2, 3, 4];

let list2 = list;

// if I modify list2 now

list2.push(5);

console.log(list); // list also gets modified as ,they are reference type
```

So what you can do

```
const onFormSubmitHandler = (data) => {
         let list2=[...list]; // creating a new variable from existing one 
        list2.push(data)
        setList(list2);
    }
```

or

```
const onFormSubmitHandler = (data) => {
         
        setList(prev=>([...prev,data]));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that your state cant be modificate with push, because the way to modificate it is with the method set

Use this code in the method `onFormSubmitHandler`

```
const onFormSubmitHandler = (data) => {
  setList(list => ([...list, data]))
}
```

Lastly remember if your form will be submit you need to break it with `e.prevent.default()`

Answer (score 1):

```
const onFormSubmitHandler = (data) => {
  list.push(data);
  setList([...list]);
}
```

Comment: Even if it works its a bad approach, you should not try to modify the list variable.

Comment: Theres nothing to be jealous of, its just a bad practice and you shouldnt be spreading it.

Answer (score 0):

You are editing it the wrong way, you should directly give the new values to the setList function and not try to update the list variable. Thats why you have the function, so that you do not update the original value. What you have to do here is use the previous state within the function and the spread operator since its an array and u just want to add an item:

```
const onFormSubmitHandler = (data) => {
  setList(prevList => [...prevList, data])
}
```

You should look at the `list` variable as a read-only variable and not attempt to modify it, you modify it through the `setList` function.

If you want to do some other modifications instead of just adding item:

```
const onFormSubmitHandler = (data) => {
  let listCopy = [...list];
  // do something with listCopy
  setList(listCopy);
}
```

In addition, it seems like you are not sending data at all to the function, the way to send data with your function call is to do it with anonymous function in the component:

```
<Component onSubmit={(e) => { onFormSubmitHandler(e.target.value) }} />
```

Comment: @GauravThakur thanks, please accept answer if it is correct for your question:)

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this

```
import List from '@material-ui/core/List'
import ListTile from "./components/ListTile/ListTile"
import style from './App.module.css'
import InputField from "./components/inputField/InputField";

const App = () => {
    const [list, setList] = useState([])

    const onFormSubmitHandler = (data) => {
        list.push(data)
        setList(list)
    }

    return (
        <div className={style.outerDiv}>
            <h1 className={style.center}>CLister</h1>
            <InputField onSubmit={(e) => onFormSubmitHandler(e.target.value)}/>
            <List component="nav">
                {list.map((data, index) =>
                     <ListTile index={index} body={data}/>
                )}
            </List>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App
```

Comment: This is the same code as in  the question ,this is what user actually doing :/.Strange and you got upvote too